# How to open the current page in chrome in a different browser window without reloading it?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I want to open the current page that i'm working in a different browser window.
 I know `window.open()` works but it loads the page by the given url. I want to display the current page that i'm working in a different browser window on a button click(preferably). Any help regarding this is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use the JavaScript `window.location.href` property to get the entire URL of the current page which includes host name, query string, fragment identifier, etc.

So using: `window.open(window.location.href)` should work

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i want the newly opened window to be the exact same window that i was working on, like when you drag a tab out of chrome it will remain as it is(without reloading). Something like that will be cool